# Android youtube api using viewPager

Tags: android, youtube-api, fragment

i am newbie and i'm trying to show youtube video using youtube api fragment.
I already search and trying to find this problem, but can't find the right answer.
So,I want to show he youtube video using viewpager. at the first pager for youtube, and the other for images. so I try to implement youtube api on fragment.
And i got this error.

Here's my java code :

```
public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

YouTubePlayerView youTubeView; 
String URL_VIDEO = "CaA-k1l0xa4";
String KEY_DEVELOPER = "api key";


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_gallery, container, false);


    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);

    youTubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(KEY_DEVELOPER, new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,
                boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            arg1.cueVideo(URL_VIDEO);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
                YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
```

Here's My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my log cat :

```
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582): Process: com.indomultimedia.hellobali, PID: 27582
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onStart(Unknown Source)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1751)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:468)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:38 2)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2505)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at  android.view.View.measure(View.java:17357)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1316)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at     android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1513)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6388)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-21 03:57:32.042: E/AndroidRuntime(27582):    at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone can help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

Before you call initialize, first create the YouTubePlayerSupportFragment by

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubeFragment =
                new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment().newInstance();
```

Then commit it by

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubeFragment).commit();
```

I saw some examples using getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager(). Not sure which one is more correct.

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() works for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar, this is what I believe you should do:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                
tools:context="com.examples.ViewPagerWithVideo$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@drawable/image_1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment_view_pager_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your Activity should be something like this:

```
public class ViewPagerWithVideo extends Activity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pager_with_video);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_pager_with_video, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        int[] images = new int[] {R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_2 };

        private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager_with_video, container, false);

            int sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            if (sectionNumber > 0) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(images[sectionNumber % images.length]);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                    YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerFragment();
                    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment_view_pager_placeholder, youTubePlayerFragment, YouTubePlayerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                    transaction.commit();
                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_fragment_view_pager_placeholder).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
            String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
                // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
                getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
            }
        }

        protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
            return (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YouTubePlayerFragment.class.getSimpleName());
        }
    }

}
```

Put specific attention to the fact that I'm not using a static fragment, it's dynamically created in the onCreateView of the PlaceholderFragment. Also I'm using a ViewPager with a SectionsPagerAdapter that extends a FragmentPagerAdapter. And I have to sample images in the drawable folders, if you want to try I added this gist:
https://gist.github.com/moxi/953b985bcd41d9fcde7a

to create the drawable folders easily and the you can put your sample images.